# I cannot find the input debugger panel

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and I am trying to connect my controller by following a tutorial on YouTube and I can't find the debugger panel. I am using unity 2019 if that could be a problem? This may not be the place to ask, I just can't find anything about anyone else not being able to see it.
I followed the tutorial exactly. The only problem is when I installed it no message came up, so that could also be the problem?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=105&v=p-3S73MaDP8&feature=emb_title

[image]

Comment: did you install the input package? did you restart like Brackeys said?

Comment: I forgot to add that, but yes i followed the tutorial exactly. The only problem is when i installed it no message came up.

Comment: which message?  the one about the device being connected? Well it worked for me i just made a blank project imported input package the debug window is available. PS you might wanna try getting off an alpha version considering how old that is

Comment: FYI https://imgur.com/7HIsUrx.jpg

Comment: nothing came up as soon as i imported the input package, but i get the message that the controller is connected.

Comment: well as alphas are expected to eat your children, if there are issues its not entirely surprising

Comment: it does make sense why we are both here then i guess

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The solution that I had in Vesion 2020 was :

1. Open the Package Manager
2. Activate de Packages source : Unity Registry
3. Search : Input
4. Install it correctly
5. Return on Menu : Window > Analysis > Input Debugger
6. Enjoy !

[Figure 1 - Package Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arFJd.png)

Comment: had to do just that in version 2022.3